# Why does inverting method call order also invert execution time?

Tags: c#, performance

I implemented two methods that do the same thing: read json files and iterate on the lines and create objects. I have no performance issues, but just by curiosity I measured the time each method takes to run as follows:

```
  var sw = new Stopwatch();
  sw.Start();

  var res1 = Method1();

  sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("method 1: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  sw.Reset();
  sw.Start();

  var res2 = Method2();

  sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine("method 2: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

First method run in about 70ms and second one about 10ms. Both methods read the same files, but first one uses arrays for processing and second uses Lists.

**Question**

The thing is, when I invert the order of the calls, the time it takes for each method to run then becomes 70ms for second method (executed first) and 10ms for first method (executed second). So the implementations are equivalent and it appears that it's the calling order that matters, as there are no shared objects, no threads, no async or parallel processing.

Why is that?

Comment: Any chance that both methods read the same files? Yet make them to read identical but different files and you may get the same timing (also hit time may also play here- that’s why when actually measure time you run code once first and then time 1000x calls)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Indeed, they are reading the same files. I run 100x the same method (first one) and only the first run was "slow", the subsequent runs were indeed faster as you said. However I copied the files with different name so each method reads it's "own" files and result is identical: method executed first is slower. What do you mean by "hit time"?

Comment: I mean JIT (as explained in Ron Beyer's answer) not "hit", sorry for confusion. Measuring  perf is hard - just look at things you care about. In this case 2 things would be most impactful - caching of compiled code by JIT (the first access to a method costs a lot) and caching of file content (roughly first access to "small" file cost more due to reading from disk and than who knows when it goes out of cache - search for something like  "C# measure performance for cold disk cache")

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the way .NET works. The first run through the code, it JIT's the output into machine code that is faster to run the second time around. So the first method will always be slower, even if it uses the same code path as the second one.

Comment: But the two code paths are distinct, right? Is it safe to assume that calling the first method makes the JIT optimize the second method to work faster? I am tempted to attribute it to something like disk caching...

Comment: @OmairMajid The first call might be, but you said they are doing the same thing, like creating JSON files. It's those lower shared methods that are being optimized and run faster the second time...

Comment: @RonBeyer I am the OP ;) Methods are doing functionally the same thing but not sharing any code nor calling common code. They are reading the same files though. It is related to the order of execution and as Omair said, the feeling is that somehow data gets cached.